# Virologically Correct Wart-Causing Toad

Tags: viruses

It was once believed that warts could be caught from a toad. At first glance, this seems like something that could plausibly be true

Unfortunately, warts are caused by HPV, the human papillomavirus. And toads, as it happens, are not humans

However, I am still determined to have warts caught from toads in my fantasy world, and so I would like a reason for why a toad's skin might be so loaded with HPV

The warts must be true warts, rather than just random skin lumps. Also, the toads cannot be truly infected themselves (it's not toad papillomavirus after all)

The world is almost completely like ours; toads are toadly, humans are humanly, and overall the only relevant difference is that touching a toad might put you in want of wart cream

Is there any realistic justification for why toads can pass on HPV and cause warts?

Comment: Is there any realistic justification for why toads can pass on HPV and cause warts? Yes, there is!

Comment: Yes they can (lol)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Toads do have papillomaviruses!**

Papillomaviruses are a huge group.  They probably occur in every animal lineage.

[Discovery of Novel Viruses Associated With the Invasive Cane Toad](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8450580/)

> Rhinella marina papillomavirus 1 is related to two other
> papillomaviruses infecting toad and fish: Oreolalax rhodostigmatus
> (Guizhou lazy toad) PV1 (OrPV1) and Sparus aurata (gilt-head bream)
> papillomavirus 1. These form distinct
> lineages from first papillomaviruses (Figure 3B), indicating a huge
> unsampled pool of papillomaviruses in cold-blooded hosts perhaps
> comprising additional members of the Secondpapillomavirinae.

It is possible for a virus that causes no problem in typical hosts to cause problems in atypical hosts.

[Metagenomic Discovery of 83 New Human Papillomavirus Types in Patients with Immunodeficiency](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6291628/)

> Individuals with a rare group of genetic immunodeficiencies
> collectively known as epidermodysplasia verruciformis (EV), including
> but not exclusively those with a deficiency in EVER1 or EVER2 proteins
> (3, 4) typically present with flat warts across various skin surfaces
> as the sole clinical manifestation. The lesions are caused by genus
> Beta HPV types, such as HPV5 and HPV8, that normally infect the hair
> follicles and skin of most healthy adults without causing warts...

Recent history has excellent examples of viruses that jump to humans from animal hosts where they do not cause much problem.  HIV is an example.  Ebola is an example.  SARS and COVID are examples.

Your toads carry papillomavirus among other viruses.  Healthy toads do fine with their endogenous viruses.  In your world, toad papillomavirus happens to cause some serious issues when it gets onto humans.  You could call them warts.

Quick shout out to the Guizhou lazy toads.  Keep up the good not work, lazy toads!